# how to pass variable from one blade to another blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass value from `order` blade to `receipt` blade. But getting error in `order.blade.php`

**order controller**

```
$var['1'] = 'hello';
$var['2'] = 'hello2';

return \Redirect::back()->with([

      'print' => 1,
      'var'=> $var

     ]);
```

**order blade**

```
<div class="modal-body">
     @include('orders.receipt', ['data' => $session['var']])                  
</div>
```

**receipt blade**

```
<td class="tableitem"><p class="itemtext">{{ session('var.1') }}</p></td>
```

**Getting error**

> Undefined variable: session (View:
> E:\xampp\htdocs\pos\resources\views\orders\order.blade.php)

Anybody help please?

Comment: use `Session::get('var')` instead of `$session['var']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data inside the order.blade.php with `Session::get('var');`

After that, you can access the defined data inside receipt.blade.php with the `$data` variable.

Comment: if I use `$data` inside receipt it giving error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.... if I use `{!! $data!!}` got error `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Yes. That is because you are sending an array into the blade template. If you directly use the array key (Example: `$data[1]`), then you won't see that error.

Comment: I already used it and get error.... `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`

Comment: How about `$data['1']`?

Comment: also getting same error.... run command `composer update`...... but still no change